# Unit testing a file reading function

Tags: c#, unit-testing

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
public class SerializeFileHandler
{
    public void WriteListToFile(MyProject myProject, string filePath)
    {
        FileStream outFile;
        BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        outFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        bFormatter.Serialize(outFile, myProject);

        // Close file
        outFile.Close();
    }

    public MyProject ReadListFromFile(String filePath)
    {
        FileStream inFile;
        BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter(); 
        MyProject myProject = new MyProject();

        // Open file for input
        inFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        // Obtain objects from file via serialization
        myProject = (MyProject)bFormatter.Deserialize(inFile);

        inFile.Close();
        return myProject;
     }
}
```

To save the data file I use `public const string myProjectFile = "myproject.dat";` and then to save any new data to the file when the user clicks the Save button I do `serializeFileHandler.WriteListToFile();` with parameters in the parentheses of course.

What I want to do is write a unit test or multiple tests if needed to test the functionality in terms of reading the data file into the application. Currently the data file is automatically loaded in when the program loads (Just does a `ReadListFromFile` on the `serializeFileHandler`.

I have created the test using the test wizard within Visual Studio but I am not sure how I'd construct the test to automate the testing of the file reading functionality. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you have tried and what your problem is, please try to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I'd have a ReadListFromStream method and then I'd inject test streams to chcek that myProject was loaded up correctly.

To Test from file
I'd stub ReadListFromStream, and simply make sure ReadListFromFile called it.

Comment: Do you have an example of what the code might look like for something like that? I'm relatively new in terms of dealing with serialized files within C# so a lot of it is completely new to me.

Comment: It would look like the the file when you open it. Looking at it, might be better off with an integration test. Create a thingy, call WriteToFile. Create another with ReadFromFile from that file and then compare the two instances. What you are testing here is the file system, which is low value and serialisation markup which is high value and barely looked at.

Comment: I'm just a bit muddled as I get quite confused thinking how to actually implement the tests into my code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that `SerializeFileHandler` has at the moment is that it has a dependency on `FileStream` which in turn ties it to reading from the file system; in order to write a test for it currently, we actually need to interact with the file system.

We can break the dependency on the file system by introducing a **test seam** that will allow us to mock/stub/fake the behaviour of the `FileStream`. In the production system, we'll pass `SerializeFileHandler` a `FileStream` to work with, but in unit tests, we'll pass it something that adheres to the interface of a `FileStream` that `SerializeFileHandler` is using but will allow us to control the behaviour for test purposes.

First, we can introduce an interface for a stream that interacts with the file system

```
public interface IFileStreamSource
{
   Stream Open(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share);
}
```

and let `SerializeFileHandler` take a dependency on this

```
public class SerializeFileHandler
{  
    private readonly IFileStreamSource _source;

    public SerializeFileHandler(IFileStreamSource source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }


    public void WriteListToFile(MyProject myProject, string filePath)
    {
        using (var stream = _source.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            bFormatter.Serialize(stream, myProject);
        }
    }

    public MyProject ReadListFromFile(String filePath)
    {
        MyProject myProject = null;

        using (var stream = _source.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter(); 

            // Obtain objects from file via serialization
            myProject = (MyProject)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }

        return myProject;
     }
}
```

Now, you can use a mocking library such as [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) to create a `Mock<IFileStreamSource>()`, likely returning a `MemoryStream`, in your unit tests and set expectations for when `Open()` is called.

In your production code, you may decide to create a parameterless constructor for `SerializeFileHandler` that passes an instance of an `IFileStreamSource` to the constructor that takes an `IFileStreamSource`, which will return an instance of `FileStream` when `Open()` is called (a la ["Poor Man's Dependency Injection"](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/)), or you may already be using an IoC/Dependency Injection container already, in which case you would simply register the component for the `IFileStreamSource` service.

Looking at the code currently, I can see a few cases that are not handled in `ReadListFromFile`, such as if the file does not exist or the file does exist but cannot be deserialized to an instance of `MyProject`. You may want to write tests for the cases and update the code accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need your tests to interact with the file system you can create a mock file system wrapper as other suggested, or create an isolated file system your test can use. I prefer the second approach, as with it the test is more similar to reality.

Prior to the test being run, set up a folder with all the files the test needs. Then have the code in the test access that folder, instead of the folder accessed by the actual code. That way, you can read the file, test how your code works if the file is missing, and also test file creation.